# Make a HTTP-proxy use a tun/tap device

Tags: vpn, squid, http-proxy, tun

I am trying to make it possible for a tool I use to connect via VPN to the network in my University. The problem with that is, that I am just able to generate a tun/tap device. The tool itself does not support using a specific network interface BUT it supports using a HTTP-proxy.

So now I am looking for a HTTP-Proxy which I can bind to a specific interface (tun device) in order to let the tool connect to my VPN via this HTTP-proxy.

I have looked at privoxy an squid but I couldn't find a hint thtat they support it.

Do you know any HTTP-proxy that supports what I plan to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe just binding to a tun interface is not enough. Since the packets coming into your HTTP-proxy will be IP packet, you will also need some TCP stack in the proxy code which can terminate the connect. Lwip is a stack for embedded device which seems full-featured. Maybe you can use that to terminate the connection and proxy it out.

Also, neither squid nor privoxy support tuntap device.

Hope this helps.